# Are there any Amazon Route 53 GUI tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Do you know any [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) GUI tools out there, other than [MyR53DNS](https://myr53dns.com/)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you don't like MyR53DNS?

Comment: simply, its not working over https, the certificate is assigned to completly different domain...

Comment: I think this should remain open.  This is a good question that will open avenues for developers who may wonder if the they can better utilize DNS services.  Building cloud applications?  You probably need to know about dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made a GUI client of Amazon Route 53.

See https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/r53-fox

Comment: again, excellent work! stand-alone, plugin all what you want, great stuff!!! thanks for that :-)

Comment: Just in case the link is lost, this tool moved to https://github.com/cookpad/r53-fox

Answer (score 12):

Amazon [lists several](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?WhereGoFromHere.html).

I personally like [Interstate53](https://interstate53.com/) -- it's a simple and straightforward web-based GUI.  (Minor gotcha: Your changes are not saved until you click "push changes" on the zones overview page.)

**Edit:** I just tried [cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53), a Python-based command-line client, and it seems very easy to use -- definitely much easier for humans than Amazon's XML interface.  Bonus points for being open source, so I can trust it with my credentials without this icky feeling of not knowing where they might go.

Comment: good hints. have you tried winebarrel's r53-fox?

Comment: +1 for interstate53.com -- they have been quick with supporting new route53 features.

Answer (score 5):

The [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) supports [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) as of November 16, 2011.

See [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#rt53) for a sneak peak and the launch blog post [AWS Management Console Now Supports Amazon Route 53](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/11/aws-management-console-now-supports-amazon-route-53.html) for a *walk through the entire process of registering a domain at a registrar and setting it up in Route 53*.

Answer (score 2):

One is available for Android, called Area 53.  It can be found on the Android Market. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vistagalleria.route53client

Answer (score 1):

Thanks BigJoe for mentioning DNS30 [ http://www.dns30.com
I am one of the developer team member of DNS30 (web based user interface), We are working on a GUI tool for Amazon route 53 also, it will be launched asps.

Regards-

Udit

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ylastic](http://www.ylastic.com) for a lot of Amazon configuration and monitoring. Yes, it's pay-for, but I have important systems running on Amazon and it's a cut above all the other Amazon GUI tools, I save the monthly fee x10 in time.

Answer (score 1):

I've build one over the weekend. It's a web-based interface for AWS Route 53 service and based on the latest Route 53 API version.

https://nsroute.com/

Try it and leave a feedback.

Thanks

Comment: There is a bug, where *.example.com. show up as \052.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Now Amazon introduces an Amazon Route 53 console in the AWS Management Console.

So now you get AWS console benefits while working with Route 53.

Answer (score 1):

We built a user interface for Route 53 called [DNSly](http://www.dnsly.net) that also supports other providers like Rackspace's Cloud DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a web-based gui for Route53 called dns30

http://www.dns30.com

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a decent list here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?WhereGoFromHere.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually use R53 fox - a firefox plugin.

Comment: The repo for this plugin has been deleted. :(

Comment: its available on git now....:)

Answer (score 0):

Try my companies solution, StackStudio at http://www.transcendcomputing.com

It has full AWS coverage (all of the services) and can be used to manage OpenStack, Eucalyptus, Rackspace, etc.

Comment: you forgot to mention this is your product